# Can I get a premium TF2 account that's able to trade if I receive an old gift copy?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I picked up TF2 when it became free. I want to be able to trade, and my friend got a copy of TF2 from the Potato Sack Pack.  If I get that copy, will I get a premium account?

Comment: I *think* so, but I'm not sure, nor how I could test that.

Comment: Why not just try it?  Either you do and you have a premium account, or you don't and your friend's gift copy is pointless now that it's free.  But I'm with @Raven, I bet it will get you a premium account

Comment: To add on to what the above commentators said, your best bet is just try it yourself. After which you can then post it as an answer to your own question, and get double the up votes.

Answer (score 9):

You *will* receive premium. See the [TF2 FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php).

Comment: Not only that, but you will receive the Proof of Purchase hat.